# F# Реализовать функцию, вычисляющую число сочетаний из m по n

Tags: f#

Как реализовать функцию, вычисляющую число сочетаний из m  по n, если нельзя пользоваться встроенными функциями модуля List?

Comment: а зачем list, если есть прямая формула - `m! / (m-n)!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не простая задача, некоторое время назад сам с ней столкнулся. Мне тогда помогли найти подходящее решение, поэтому просто скопирую его сюда:

```
let rec combinations acc size set = seq {
    match size, set with
      | n, x::xs ->
          if n > 0 then yield! combinations (x::acc) (n - 1) xs
          if n >= 0 then yield! combinations acc n xs
      | 0, [] -> yield acc
      | _, [] -> () }
```

Автор : **s952163**

[Источник](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/51909?m=29850440#29850440)

Использование:

```
combinations [] 5 [1..6]
|> printfn "%A"
```

Для более удобного использования советую сделать обертку над функцией `combinations`

Answer (score 2):

Решение по формуле, без использования функций списка

```
let factorial n =
    let rec loop i acc =
        match i with
        | 0 | 1 -> acc
        | _ -> loop (i-1) (acc * i)
    loop n 1

let combinations_count m n =
    (factorial m) / (factorial (m-n))
```

Можно немного улучить, сведя к произведению чисел от m-n+1 до n и использовав методы List:

```
let combinations_count_short m n =
    [m-n+1..m] |> List.reduce (*)
```